# Retaining the previous row value of currently mutated variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is my dataset and I'm trying to use the previous row value of my currently mutated value in dplyr. first(start_time) wouldn't work because there's a group_by happening before this code hence the first refers to the first one in group which isn't what I want.

This is the code that I am trying:

```
mutate(shift_start_time = if_else(diff==0 | diff > 21600,start_time,lag(shift_start_time)))
```

But `shift_start_time` being the currently mutated variable isn't available for operation and I'm struggling for any other work around.

Current:

```
# A tibble: 703 × 4
            start_time            end_time      diff    shift_start_time
                <dttm>              <dttm>    <time>              <dttm>
1  2017-05-01 14:21:00 2017-05-01 14:42:18    0 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
2  2017-05-01 14:48:00 2017-05-01 15:08:17  342 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
3  2017-05-01 15:14:00 2017-05-01 15:35:31  343 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
4  2017-05-01 15:42:00 2017-05-01 15:45:36  389 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
5  2017-05-01 15:50:00 2017-05-01 16:51:47  264 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
6  2017-05-01 16:39:00 2017-05-01 16:51:22 -767 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
7  2017-05-01 17:37:00 2017-05-01 17:51:57 2738 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
8  2017-05-01 17:46:00 2017-05-01 17:58:25 -357 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
9  2017-05-01 17:59:00 2017-05-01 18:11:16   35 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
10 2017-05-01 18:08:00 2017-05-01 18:22:22 -196 secs 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Required:

```
# A tibble: 703 × 4
            start_time            end_time      diff    shift_start_time
                <dttm>              <dttm>    <time>              <dttm>
1  2017-05-01 14:21:00 2017-05-01 14:42:18    0 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
2  2017-05-01 14:48:00 2017-05-01 15:08:17  342 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
3  2017-05-01 15:14:00 2017-05-01 15:35:31  343 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
4  2017-05-01 15:42:00 2017-05-01 15:45:36  389 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
5  2017-05-01 15:50:00 2017-05-01 16:51:47  264 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
6  2017-05-01 16:39:00 2017-05-01 16:51:22 -767 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
7  2017-05-01 17:37:00 2017-05-01 17:51:57 2738 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
8  2017-05-01 17:46:00 2017-05-01 17:58:25 -357 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
9  2017-05-01 17:59:00 2017-05-01 18:11:16   35 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
10 2017-05-01 18:08:00 2017-05-01 18:22:22 -196 secs 2017-05-01 14:21:00
```

Comment: Why not separate into two mutate statements? Curiosity?

Comment: could you `ungroup()` first?

Comment: You can add the rownames to the data frame as an additional column and then use the rownames as you would any other column: `df %>% rownames_to_column() %>% mutate(...`. `rownames_to_column()` is a convenience function, but you can also do `mutate(row = rownames(.))`.